# Getting a column into an array from excel in python

Tags: python, arrays, excel, csv

As part of a project I am doing, I need to create a league table and in order for it to be ordered by points, I need to access the points column from excel and order it. So far the code I have written for this is:

```
output = []
x = open("table.csv", "rU")
for line in x:
    cells = line.split(",")
    output.append((cells[7]))
print output
```

Points is the last of all the columns with 7 in total. The output for this is:

```
['Points\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n']
```

Is there a way to get to just the figures and then order them without using pandas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv), it will help you to do this.

Looking at the code that you already have, you want to skip over the column header and also call `strip()` on the "cell" to remove the new line. Before outputing, sort the output list:

```
output = []
with open("table.csv", "rU") as x:
    next(x)    # skip header row
    for line in x:
        cells = line.split(",")
        output.append((cells[7].strip()))
output.sort()
print output
```

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
with open("table.csv", "rU") as f:
    output = sorted([line.split(',')[7].strip() for line in f][1:])
```

Or you can use the CSV module:

```
import csv

with open("table.csv", "rU") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    output = sorted(row[7] for row in reader)
```

Comment: @RobertAvill : no problem. Please consider up-voting and accepting this answer if your problem is solved.